# copy file with specified name into specific location

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I wrote a function that copies file to specific location, but i am trying to make few tweaks to this function.Below function copies **hire_date** data from a table to a **datafinal.csv** file .

I'm trying to append **max(hire_date)** to a **datafinal.csv** file name.

eg: **datafinal_20190302.csv**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION exportfile_csv()
RETURNS integer as $$
declare rows integer;
BEGIN
    copy (select hire_date from mytable)
    to program 'cat > /data/backup/file_out/datafinal.csv'
    With CSV header;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS rows=ROW_COUNT;
    return rows;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately expressions other than literals won't work for the target path. But you can build the command as a string and `EXECUTE` it, like in:

```
EXECUTE 'COPY (SELECT hire_date FROM mytable) TO PROGRAM ''cat > /data/backup/file_out/datafinal_' || to_char(now(), 'YYYYMMDD') || '.csv'' WITH CSV HEADER;';
```

And you probably don't need the `cat` detour, just

```
EXECUTE 'COPY (SELECT hire_date FROM mytable) TO ''/data/backup/file_out/datafinal_' || to_char(now(), 'YYYYMMDD') || '.csv'' WITH CSV HEADER;';
```

should work.